# I cannot create a simple table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, create-table

I try to Write the SQL code to create the table named ‘EMP_1’. This table is a subset of the EMPLOYEE table, and the structure of the table is summarized as shown below.
This is the information:

```
Attribute Name    Data Type    Remarks
EMP_NUM           CHAR(3)      PK
EMP_LNAME         VARCHAR(15)  Not Null
EMP_FNAME         VARCHAR(15)  Not Null
EMP_INITIAL       CHAR(1)    
EMP_HIREDATE      DATE    
JOB_CODE          CHAR(3)      FK (from JOB table)
```

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_1
(
EMP_NUM  CHAR(3)     PRIMARY KEY,
EMP_LNAME   VARCHAR(15)  Not Null,
EMP_FNAME    VARCHAR(15)    Not Null,
EMP_INITIAL  CHAR(1)    ,
EMP_HIREDATE    DATETIME,
JOB_CODE CHAR(3) FOREIGN KEY (JOB_CODE) REFERENCES JOB(JOB_CODE)
);
```

I keep getting CONSTRAINT error

Comment: Do you have a JOB table with a JOB_CODE column in your database?

Comment: Is JOB_CODE a primary key?

Comment: yes I do have JOB_CODE in my JOB table

Comment: No JOB_CODE is my FK not PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing a comma before the constraint. This worked when I tried it:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_1
(
  EMP_NUM CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  EMP_LNAME VARCHAR(15) Not Null,
  EMP_FNAME VARCHAR(15) Not Null,
  EMP_INITIAL CHAR(1),
  EMP_HIREDATE DATETIME,
  JOB_CODE CHAR(3), 
  CONSTRAINT FK_JOBS FOREIGN KEY (JOB_CODE) REFERENCES JOB(JOB_CODE)
);
```

Comment: It said query must have at least one destination field

Comment: It might be that you need to set the database to SQL92 mode, in the menu "Tools > Options"/"Tables or queries", check if "Syntax compatible with SQL Server (ANSI 92)" is set for the current database.

Comment: I am using ms access 2007 where is tool

Comment: It was a long time since I used Access 2007, and I'm not sure exactly where the option is, but it should be under options in the tools menu. In Access 2010 it's under File/Options/Object Designers.

Comment: Make sure the option for SQL 92 syntax is selected and try to run the query again.

Comment: OH it work, thanks very much. NOW I can do my assignment, please give your email to me so that If I have any other question, I might can ask you. PLEASE

Comment: @2h2h2h Happy it worked. If you have further questions, please ask them here on Stack Overflow and not by e-mail, I'm not a personal support service ;)

Comment: Sorry to make you think that. hey thanks for your help now I can do my work have a good night sir

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY have the same DATA TYPE.

Comment: How? I am a noob in this SQL

Comment: but my JOB_CODE and EMP_NUM is in the same type of data, CHAR

Answer (score 0):

I've not scrpited a FK for a while, but my recollection is that you can EITHER use:

JOB_CODE CHAR(3) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES JOB(JOB_CODE)
which will create an FK named JOB_CODE,

OR:
split the line so you create the field and add the constraint separately as per JPW's response.

Your original code tries to combine the 2 approaches which will throw the error you describe.